# Use JQuery plugin with Webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, galleria

I am trying to use the plugin [Galleria](https://galleria.io) with Webpack. Without Webpack galleria can be used as:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="galleria/galleria-1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
  (function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.5.7/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('.galleria');
  }());
</script>
```

The theme can also be loaded manually instead of using the method `loadTheme`:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.5.7/themes/fullscreen/galleria.classic.min.css” />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>   
<script src=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.5.7/galleria.min.js”></script>
<script src=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.5.7/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js”></script>

<script>
  (function() {
    Galleria.run('.galleria');
  }());
</script>
```

With WebPack I added the following code to Index.js:

```
import galleria from 'galleria';

import '../../node_modules/galleria/dist/themes/classic/galleria.classic.css';
import '../../node_modules/galleria/dist/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js';

window.Galleria = galleria; 

(function() {
  Galleria.run('.galleria');
}());
```

When I run it I get the errors:

```
No theme CSS loaded.

Init failed: Galleria could not find the element "undefined".
```

Any idea how to use Galleria with Webpack?

Comment: From the FAQ on the Galleria site: "Galleria does not work with webpack - If you are using webpack, you will need to use shimming as Galleria requires access to the window.location object:" https://galleria.io/docs/references/faq.html

Comment: Yes, I did that by adding the rule in Webpack and still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created a simple [repo](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-galleria-example) with webpack and galleria for you.
Steps are:

1. Use `shimming` as documented [here](https://galleria.io/docs/references/faq.html):

```
            {
                test: /galleria.js$/,
                loader: "imports-loader?this=>window"
            },
```

2. Add `jquery` and `galleria` as dependencies to your project:
   `npm i -S jquery galleria`
3. Use `loadTheme` and `run` Galleria methods:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import galleria from 'galleria';

window.Galleria = galleria;
window.jQuery = $;

Galleria.loadTheme('node_modules/galleria/dist/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');
Galleria.run('.galleria');
```

To see project working please run `npm run start`.

**UPD:**
To copy minified theme files you can use `CopyWebpackPlugin`:

1. `npm i -D copy-webpack-plugin`
2. Add it to webpack plugins:

```
plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'node_modules/galleria/dist/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js', to: 'assets/galleria.classic.js' },
            { from: 'node_modules/galleria/dist/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.css', to: 'assets/galleria.classic.css' },
        ])
]
```

3. Change path in `loadTheme` call: `Galleria.loadTheme('assets/galleria.classic.js');`

**UPD2:**
Updated repo with webpack `imports` usage.
Please see difference in this [PR](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-galleria-example/pull/1/files) or this [branch](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-galleria-example/tree/feature/galleria-imports).
Main changes are:

1. We still need `galleria.classic.css` file to be used with `copy-webpack-plugin` and loaded as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/galleria.classic.css">` because I found in source code that `css` can be loaded only through `link` or `script` tags or dynamically (`loadTheme` call), otherwise `No theme css loaded` will be printed.
   [image: source]

   2. But then our javascript code becomes pretty simple. Also I removed webpack rule with `imports-loader` and used it in inline style.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as Galleria from 'galleria'
import 'imports-loader?define=>false!./node_modules/galleria/src/themes/classic/galleria.classic';

Galleria.run('.galleria');
```

Comment: Thank you. That "kind" of work ... I needed to copy manually `galleria.classic.js` and `galleria.classic.css" files to project assets folder because when I run my project the path in node_modules is not found. Is there a way to copy those two files to project assets folder on build?

Comment: @MiguelMoura updated the answer and repo. I think my solution is not the best because with webpack it is better to use `import` statements than `loadTheme` method, but it works. if I will have some free time I will look for a solution with imports.

Comment: Thank you. If you could add an example with import that would be great. But I already accepted your answer anyway.

Comment: @MiguelMoura upd :)

Comment: I feel like I've searched the whole internet to find a solution to this problem. Thanks for helping out @nick.

However, I still had issues while trying to load the theme.

The solution that I found is to fetch the theme from a CDN inside the HTML (or .ftl file in my case): `Galleria.loadTheme('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.6.1/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');`.